# Не получается адекватно прочитать файл

Tags: java

Читаю книгу Барри Берта. Переписываю код символ-в-символ из самой книги, но что-то не сходится. Во фрейме появляются только цифры, а имена не отображаются. Вот сам код:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
public class Player {

    private String name;
    private double average;

    public Player (String name, double average){
        this.name = name;
        this.average = average;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public double getAverage(){
        return average;
    }

    public String getAverageString(){
        DecimalFormat decFormat = new DecimalFormat();
        decFormat.setMaximumIntegerDigits(0);
        decFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(3);
        decFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(3);
        return decFormat.format(average);
    }
}
```

ВТОРОЙ КЛАСС

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TeamFrame extends JFrame {


    public TeamFrame() throws IOException {
        Player player;
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (new File ("Hankees.txt"));

        for (int num = 1; num<=9; num++){
             player = new Player(keyboard.nextLine(),
                                 keyboard.nextDouble());
            keyboard.nextLine();

            addPlayerInfo(player);
        }

        setTitle ("Средние бэттинги Ханков");
        setLayout(new GridLayout(9, 2, 20, 3));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    void addPlayerInfo(Player player) {
        add (new JLabel (" "+ player.getAverageString()));
    }


}
```

ТРЕТИЙ КЛАСС - - -

```
import java.io.IOException;

class Num{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{

        new TeamFrame();
    }
}
```

ТЕКСТОВЫЙ ДОКУМЕНТ (Название "Henkees.txt", корневая папка) - - -

```
Barry Burd
,101
Harriet Ritter
,200
Weelie J.Katz
,030
Harry "The Crazyman" Spoonswagler
,124
Filicia "Fishy" Katz
,075
Mia, Just "Mia"
,111
Jeremy Flooflong Jones
,102
I.M. D'Arthur
,001
Hugh R.DaReader
,212
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А откуда у вас там имена должны появиться, если

```
void addPlayerInfo(Player player) {
    add (new JLabel (" "+ player.getAverageString()));
}
```

в этом методе у вас вызывается только `player.getAverageString()`
А внутри `getAverageString()` поле `name` не фигурирует вовсе.

Пишите так например, если имя хотите добавить:

```
void addPlayerInfo(Player player) {
    add (new JLabel (player.getName() + " " + player.getAverageString()));
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, получилось!!! Блин, в этой книге уже второй раз сталкиваюсь с такими ошибками. То ли еще будет)))

Comment: @RumDelta, не полагайтесь на автора, будьте внимательны. Ошибки допускают все, а возможно даже это не ошибка, а тест на внимательность, чтобы вы не просто перепечатывали и запускали код, а разобрались в нем ;)